# Connect 4 Android Studio Draw empty spaces

Tags: java, android, android-studio, draw

I am writing a Connect 4 app for Android Studio, but I am having trouble with drawing the empty spaces on the board, my current code only draws the white spaces for the first row. I want to implement a nested loop, but I can't get the empty spaces to draw on all rows. Adding cellSize to rowPosition makes the circles to be drawn one row below.

```
   private void drawEmptyDiscs(Canvas canvas) {
        float rowPosition = boardStartY;
        canvas.save();
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ROWS; j++) {
            canvas.translate(marginLeft, rowPosition);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; i++) {
                // FIXME: if column isn't full? E.g., if (board.isColumnOpen(i)) {
                float x = i * cellSize;
                float y = cellPadding;
                canvas.drawOval(x + cellPadding, y,
                        x + cellSize - cellPadding, cellSize - cellPadding,
                        paint);
            }
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmbn9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update y regarding to j, like:

```
float y = j * cellSize;
```

You forgot to add y to the last parameter for the oval. Draw it like:

```
canvas.drawOval(x + cellPadding, y + cellPadding,
                    x + cellSize - cellPadding, y + cellSize - cellPadding,
                    paint);
```

Comment: That makes the oval shape not fit in the spaces.

Comment: oops, maybe i made a mistake. It's already 1 am here. Are the other rows visible now?